# Adding markers on a map - labels on a lable, on button click Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

[image]I have an image of a map, in a label in my JFrame. I want to pretend like it draws markers on the map. When I click on that map, I want to draw a marker image(any image) on that specific location. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Show your attempt to do this, including your [mcve] code. But there are several ways to do this including creating an ArrayList of Points indicating where things are marked, and then drawing these marks within paintComponent, or you could draw directly on a BufferedImage. ...

Comment: Can you post  your code ?

Comment: I haven't coded anything to get the coordinators, yet. Because I cannot think of a way to draw the place on this map.

Comment: I'll bet that if you search and try, you can do better than that. Give it a go, you've nothing to lose!

Comment: [Here are some similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+draw+on+image+mouse+click). Please have a look!

Comment: These will do! thank-you so much

Comment: Note that your current question is very broad since you were asking about a multi-step process. In the future if you make an attempt before asking, even if you fail, you will be able to use that attempt to hone in on the extact step that is causing problems, allowing you to ask a much more focused and answerable question. Good luck!

Comment: Just add a label containing an ImageIcon of the the image you want to display to the map background label.